# Is there a way to call multiple functions inside one Python map function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, type-conversion, rgb

The project that I am currently working on requires me to convert RGB tuples to singular binary strings.

I am currently using `output.append(''.join(map('{:0>8}'.format, map(str, map("{0:b}".format, each)))))` to first convert each tuple element to binary, then to a string, and finally pad with zeroes before joining so it is still possible to tell each RGB element apart. It works perfectly, but I was wondering if there was a way to use only *one* `map()` instead of three?

Comment: The inner `format` already creates a string, so mapping that to `str` is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks overly complicated. Instead of

- formatting a number as a binary string
- then padding this string with zeros
- then needlessly converting this string to a string again

just use `{:08b}` to format a number as a zero-padded 8-digit binary string in one go.

You do not need to (and can't) pass multiple functions to `map`.

```
''.join(map('{:08b}'.format, each))
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation for the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) method. You will see it takes a *function* and an *iterable*. You are not constrained to a specific method or way to define the method, so it could be a lambda or a reference to a builtin or custom method. So you can simply define a function to call whatever method you'd like, and pass it as the parameter.

```py
def func(value):
    print(f"=== {value} ===")
    print("something else...")
    # any other function called you'd like

for i in map(func, [0, 1 , 2]):
    i
```

An you should see the output below:

```
=== 0 ===
something else...
=== 1 ===
something else...
=== 2 ===
something else...
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `map`, prefer list comprehensions or generators.

```
output.append(''.join('{:0>8}'.format("{0:b}".format(item)) for item in each))
```